# couldnot upload sketch in esp8266 wifi module

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

When I connect *rx-rx tx-tx* the AT commands are working, but the correct is *rx-tx* and *tx-rx* and after this when I upload a sketch it shows.

> Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_431846\core\core_esp8266_esp8266_generic_CpuFrequency_80,ResetMethod_ck,CrystalFreq_26,FlashFreq_40,FlashMode_qio,FlashSize_512K0,led_2,LwIPVariant_v2mss536,Debug_Disabled,DebugLevel_None____,FlashErase_none,UploadSpeed_115200_6664e2b9df4df9eb4895da6f09691624.a
>   Sketch uses 250800 bytes (50%) of program storage space. Maximum is 499696 bytes.
>   Global variables use 32864 bytes (40%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49056 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
>   warning: espcomm_sync failed
>   error: espcomm_open failed
>   error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
>   error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

I have searched alot about the errors, but I could not solve it.

I also downloaded the ESPTOOLS but it `FAIL` all the time showing the error:

> [2018-05-21 15:57:00,082][ESP8266Loader_spi[1]][espDownloader.pyo][line:351][ERROR]: Chip sync error: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
>   [2018-05-21 15:57:00,082][ESP8266Loader_spi[1]][espDownloader.pyo][line:439][ERROR]: ESP8266 Chip sync error esp_sync_blocking.

please help

Comment: Could you elaborate, why are you switching from rx-rx, tx-tx to rx-tx, tx-rx if you were able to use the AT commands?

Comment: Also, did you put the esp8266 into bootloader mode before trying to upload the code?

Comment: i am converting from rx-tx and tx-rx otherwise rx-rx tx-tx connection is showing error of
`warning: espcomm_send_command: can't receive slip payload data`

Comment: if bootloader is connecting gpo0 to ground and gpo1 to 3.3v . I have done it. Please tell me what i am missing.

Comment: You also need to reset the module after doing those connections. If you powered up the module with those connections then no problem. It is in bootloader mode.

Also which version of ESP is it?

Also you should not mark the flash size to 512k. I did that and bricked my esp8266-12E, the first time I uploaded a code to it.

The code worked, but the esp8266 stopped being programmable.

Comment: why is italways giving an error of `espcomm_upload_mem failed`

Comment: You probably fried the boot-loader when you used 512KB while uploading the code.

Check what version of esp8266 you are using, and what bootloader size it carries.

If you use the wrong size while uploading, your esp is programming bricked.

Comment: my wifi module being an AI thinker it has its own firmware and the AT commands are working. but on uploading a sketch only error are`espcomm_upload_mem failed `

Answer (score 0):

The **ESP8266** modules doesn't have auto-reset like Arduino when you upload the firmware. So, you need to manually RESET the module every time you attempt to upload the firmware.

Looks the diagram below:
[image]
*(I assume that you connect from source to targe: RX to TX, and TX to RX respectively)*

Also, make sure you have the right Driver for your "Serial cable", I tested using Prolific USB.